# Trouble Installing Apache Server?

Tags: apache, installation

I am installing Apache Server 2.4.6 (the most recent version) on my computer and I have been having trouble installing it. After installing apr-1.4.8 and apr-utils-1.5.2, I did a simple

```
./configure --enable-file-cache --enable-cache --enable-disk-cache --enable-mem-cache --enable-deflate --enable-expires --enable-headers --enable-usertrack --enable-ssl --enable-cgi --enable-vhost-alias --enable-rewrite --enable-so --with-apr=/usr/local/apr/
```

to configure my server. That worked perfectly. However, after that I typed `make`, I got an error after it compiled saying

```
passwd_common.o: In function `mkhash':
/root/sr/httpd-2.4.6/support/passwd_common.c:261: undefined reference to `apr_bcrypt_encode'
```

which I tried Googling but I dont know why this is happening. Might anyone know why this comes up? I followed every instruction correctly as I followed the `documentation` that said:

`download the latest versions of both APR and APR-Util from Apache APR, unpack them into ./srclib/apr and ./srclib/apr-util (be sure the domain names do not have version numbers; for example, the APR distribution must be under ./srclib/apr/)`

Might anyone have any ideas why I'm getting an `undefined reference to`apr_bcrypt_encode'`? I'm just worried because I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it once already.

Comment: You're not mentioning the LInux distro you're using (and correct me if my assumption that you're using Linux is wrong), but in *most* distros you'll need to install the dev support for apr to compile programs based on it - look for `apr-devel-1.4.8` or something along these lines.

Comment: Ah so sorry. I am using Red Hat Linux 6 and  okay I'll look into this and let you know. Thank you.